# Olá a todos. Estou tendo problemas com um código em python, apresenta o erro: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'programa'

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Sou um estudante iniciante e estou com um problema que não consigo até agora resolver sozinho, é um código da faculdade. Segue abaixo o código junto com erro:

```
from programa.modelos import Variavel

planilha = xlrd.open_workbook("dados/dicionario_pessoas.xls")
primeira_aba = planilha.sheet_by_index(0)
# print("Nome:", primeira_aba.name)
# print("Num linhas:", primeira_aba.nrows)
# print("Num colunas:", primeira_aba.ncols)
#
variaveis = []
nova_variavel = None
for idx, linha in enumerate(primeira_aba.get_rows()):
    print(linha)
    primeira_celula = linha[0]  # Atributos da celula: ctype e value
    if primeira_celula.ctype == 2:  # number
        # Nova variavel
        if nova_variavel:
            # Guarda a ultima variavel criada
            variaveis.append(nova_variavel)
        # Variaveis do construtor
        posicao_inicial = linha[0].value
        tamanho = linha[1].value
        codigo = linha[2].value
        descricao = linha[4].value
        nova_variavel = Variavel(posicao_inicial, tamanho, codigo, descricao)
        # Variaveis da primeira categoria
        categoria_tipo = linha[5].value
        categoria_descricao_tipo = linha[6].value
        nova_variavel.add_categoria({'categoria_tipo': categoria_tipo, 'categoria_descricao_tipo': categoria_descricao_tipo})
    else:
        if nova_variavel:
            # Variaveis das demais categorias
            categoria_tipo = linha[5].value
            categoria_descricao_tipo = linha[6].value
            nova_variavel.add_categoria({'categoria_tipo': categoria_tipo, 'categoria_descricao_tipo': categoria_descricao_tipo})

    # if idx > 50:
    #     break
#
print('Total de variaveis', len(variaveis))
for variavel in variaveis:
    print(variavel)
    for categ in variavel.categoria:
        print('\t', categ)
```

**Apresenta o seguinte erro:**

PS C:\Programação> & "C:/Program Files/Python311/python.exe" c:/Programação/programa/principal.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Programação\programa\principal.py", line 2, in 
from programa.modelos import Variavel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'programa'

**OBS, segue o código do modulo que estou desejando invocar a variável:**

```
    def __init__(self, posicao_inicial, tamanho, codigo, descricao):
        self.posicao_inicial = posicao_inicial
        self.tamanho = tamanho
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.descricao = descricao
        self.categoria = []

    def add_categoria(self, categoria):
        # categoria = dict {'categoria_tipo': tipo, 'categoria_descricao_tipo': descricao}
        self.categoria.append(categoria)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.codigo + " - " + self.descricao
```

**Alguém me ajuda a aprender aonde eu estou errando? Agradeço a atenção**

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ao que parece pelo que texto do erro informado, o módulo "*modelos*" está no mesmo diretório do arquivo que você está tentando executar, então para importá-lo é só usar:

```
from modelos import Variavel
```